# Insert text before a certain line using Bash

Tags: bash, shell

How can I insert a set of lines (about 5) into a file at the **first place** a string is found?

For example:

BestAnimals.txt

```
dog
cat
dolphin
cat
```

$ "Insert giraffe to BestAnimals.txt before cat" > NewBestAnimals.txt

NewBestAnimals.txt

```
dog
giraffe 
cat
dolphin
cat
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If using gnu sed:

```
$ cat animals
dog
cat
dolphin
cat

$ sed  "/cat/ { N; s/cat\n/giraffe\n&/ }" animals
dog
giraffe
cat
dolphin
cat
```

1. match a line with (/cat/)
2. continue on next line (N)
3. substitute the matched pattern with the insertion and the matched string, where `&` represent the matched string.

Comment: True, should have added that. Updated.

Comment: there is a problem when there is a `nyan cat` line first, for instance

Comment: yes, but that wasn't part of the question ;-) Start small with the simplest possible solution a.k.a. KISS and then take it from there when problem arises

Comment: That's true! I just proposed you a way to solve this.
I also found another problem: the first occurrence of `cat` cannot be on the last line. Dunno how to solve that one!

Comment: They are all valid solutions but you answered first so accepted.

Comment: how do you use this syntax for sed with a different delimiter than `/`? Every place I looked required `s` to set a different separator, but adding that to the above string didn't work.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander -- don't quite follow. Best would be if you post a new question and I'll take a look!

Comment: never mind, I made it work with a simpler test case. If you want to replace with a string that has slashes in it, changing the second argument works: `sed  "/cat/ { N; s|/cat\n|giraffe\n&| }"`

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v insert=giraffe -v before=cat '
  $1 == before && ! inserted {
    print insert
    inserted++
  }
  {print}
' BestAnimals.txt > NewBestAnimals.txt
```

Comment: define two variables `insert` that takes the value "giraffe" and dito for variable `before`. for each line: if first WS separated token e.g. "dog" matches the content of variable `before` and variable inserted isn't defined print variable `insert`  i.e. "giraffe. Increment inserted variable so that subsequent matched doesn't yield a print. Finally, default action for all lines is `print` i.e. output the input line. Beautiful solution as always from Mr @glennjackman :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you know (or somehow find out) the line:

```
sed -n '/cat/=' BestAnimals.txt
```

You can use sed:

```
sed -i '2i giraffe' BestAnimals.txt
```

Comment: How do you do this for multiple words? I get sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra characters after command

Answer (score 2):

An awk solution:

```
awk '/cat/ && c == 0 {c = 1; print "giraffe"}; {print}' \
     BestAnimals.txt
```

If the animals you want to insert are in "MyOtherBestAnimals.txt" you can also do

```
awk '/cat/ && c == 0 {c = 1; system("cat MyOtherBestAnimals.txt") }; {print} ' \
     BestAnimals.txt
```

This answer can basically be broken down as follows, because `;` separates the awk condition-action pairs:

- `/cat/ && c == 0 { c = 1; ... }` sets `c` to 1 at the first row containing cat. The commands put at the `...` are then executed, but only once, because `c` is 1 now.
- `{print}` is the action print with no condition: prints any input line. This is done after the above condition-action pair.

Depending on what is actually at the `...`, giraffe is printed, or the contents of "MyOtherBestAnimals.txt" is sent to the standard output, before printing the first line containing "cat".

**Edit**

After analysis of @glenn jackman's solution, it seems this solution can still be improved: when using input file

```
nyan cat
cat
```

the data is appended before `nyan cat` and not before the line equal to `cat`. The solution is then to request the full line to be equal to `cat`:

```
awk '$0 == "cat" && c == 0 {c = 1; print "giraffe"}; {print}' \
     BestAnimals.txt
```

for the insertion of a single line and

```
awk '$0 == "cat" && c == 0 {c = 1; system("cat MyOtherBestAnimals.txt") }; {print} ' \
     BestAnimals.txt
```

for the insertion of a file

Comment: The OP wants to insert *before cat* not *after dog*

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Use `grep` to find the line number of the first match
2. Use `head` to get the text leading up to the match
3. Insert the new content using `cat`
4. Use `tail` to get the lines after the match

It's neither quick, efficient nor elegant. But it's pretty straight-forward, and if the file isn't gigantic and/or you need to do this many times a second, it should be fine.

Comment: I'm just trying to automate a boring task because I'm a computer scientist so speed doesn't really matter, there are about 500 files!