# how to insert a line before 2-3 line of match pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

Input file:file

```
aaaa    
bbbb  
cccc  
dddd  
ffff  *  
==================  
Schedule  
end of file
```

i want to insert  zzzz before 2-3 lines of  'schedule' 
but it must check whether any word is available on that line or not.if available then insert zzzz to next line

Input file:file

```
aaaa    
bbbb  
cccc  
dddd  
ffff  * 
zzzz 
==================  

Schedule  
end of file
```

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248784/shell-bash-insert-text-before-a-certain-line

Comment: I think you could elaborate a bit more on your question. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @leekaiinthesky yes i want the same as per your given link but if there i want to skipt the 2-3 line before the match word & then paste the new word then what should i do?

Comment: I think that if you show what code you're trying and also show the problem you're having with it, then people will be able to help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what `before 2-3 lines` really means but I think this is probably what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    if (/Schedule/) {
        tgts[NR-2]
    }
    next
}
{ print }
(FNR in tgts) && /ffff/ { print "zzzz" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
ffff  *
zzzz
==================
Schedule
end of file
```