# How do we add a block before a particular string in a file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing

I have an XML file as below:

```
<Context path="/jasperserver-pro" reloadable="false">
    <Resource name="jdbc/jasperserver" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="jasperdb" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/jasperserver?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory"/>
    <Resource name="jdbc/sugarcrm" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="jasperdb" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/sugarcrm?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory"/>
    <Resource name="jdbc/foodmart" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="jasperdb" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/foodmart?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory"/>
    <Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```

I need to add a piece of code before `<Manager pathname=" "/>`.

I have the code in a variable as below:

```
    RESOURCE_BEAN="<Resource name=\"resourceBean\" auth=\"Container\" type=\"javax.sql.DataSource\"
                maxActive=\"100\" maxIdle=\"30\" maxWaitMillis=\"10000\"
                username=\"$username\" password=\"$password\"
                driverClassName=\"$classname\" url=\"$url\"/>"
```

And I am using the below command to replace but it does not work.

```
VAR1="<Manager pathname=\"\"/>"

echo "$VAR1"

sed  '/${VAR1}/i ${RESOURCE_BEAN}' context.xml
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Why not use `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` to edit XML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash insert subnode to XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962889/bash-insert-subnode-to-xml-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert multiple lines of text before specific line using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32007152/608639), [Insert text before a certain line using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12248784/608639), etc.

Comment: is it possible to achieve this without using xmllint or xmlstartlet?

Comment: @manjosh, _possible_, sure, but _a good idea_, no. XML-aware tools can be 100% guaranteed to leave your output well-formed; XML-unaware tools categorically cannot -- they don't understand comments, CDATA sections, namespaces, or all the other weirdness that can make characters in an XML file mean different things depending on other contents that aren't directly next to them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You need to escape also slashes in Your variables:

```
RESOURCE_BEAN="<Resource name=\"resourceBean\" auth=\"Container\" type=\"javax.sql.DataSource\" maxActive=\"100\" maxIdle=\"30\" maxWaitMillis=\"10000\" username=\"$username\" password=\"$password\" driverClassName=\"$classname\" url=\"$url\"\/>"
VAR1="<Manager pathname=\"\"\/>"
```

Then this sed should work for You:

```
sed 's/'"${VAR1}"'/'"${RESOURCE_BEAN}"'/'
```

Test:

```
$ cat context.xml
<Context path="/jasperserver-pro" reloadable="false">
    <Resource name="jdbc/jasperserver" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="jasperdb" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/jasperserver?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory"/>
    <Resource name="jdbc/sugarcrm" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="jasperdb" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/sugarcrm?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory"/>
    <Resource name="jdbc/foodmart" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="jasperdb" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/foodmart?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory"/>
    <Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>

$ cat context.xml | sed 's/'"${VAR1}"'/'"${RESOURCE_BEAN}"'/'
    <Context path="/jasperserver-pro" reloadable="false">
        <Resource name="jdbc/jasperserver" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="jasperdb" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/jasperserver?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory"/>
        <Resource name="jdbc/sugarcrm" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="jasperdb" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/sugarcrm?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory"/>
        <Resource name="jdbc/foodmart" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="jasperdb" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/foodmart?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory"/>
        <Resource name="resourceBean" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="" password="" driverClassName="" url=""/>
    </Context>
```

If You do not want to escape slashes in your variables You must change sed separator to pipes for instance:

```
sed 's|'"${VAR1}"'|'"${RESOURCE_BEAN}"'|'
```

Comment: echo "resouce bean ==>"

RESOURCE_BEAN="<Resource name=\"resourceBean\" auth=\"Container\" type=\"javax.sql.DataSource\"
               maxActive=\"100\" maxIdle=\"30\" maxWaitMillis=\"10000\"
               username=\"$username\" password=\"$password\"
               driverClassName=\"$classname\" url=\"$url\"\/>
     <Manager pathname=\"\"\/>"
VAR1="<Manager pathname=\"\"\/>"

sed 's/'"${VAR1}"'/'"${RESOURCE_BEAN}"'/'

i tried this but i get the error  " sed: -e expression #1, char 100: unterminated `s' command"